# ¿Cómo retornar imágenes de un array que tengo en JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estoy haciendo un sorteo usando JSON, CSS y HTML, en el que tengo un array JSON así:

```
var data = [
             {
               "label":"DELFIN",  
               "value":0,
               "name":"1",
               "question":"DELFIN",
               "png":"png/delfin.png",
               "ogg":"ogg/delfin.ogg"
             }
           ];
```

Estoy ubicando en un sitio, en mi página los elementos retornados usando:

```
        .text( function(d, i) {
            return data[i].value; // + '\n' +data[i].value;  se concateno el return para poder agregar mas cosas a la Ruleta
        });
```

Mi duda es que cuando cambio el valor retornado por png, me trae el texto "png/delfin.png" en mi HTML. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para no traer el texto sino una imagen para mostrarla donde actualmente muestro el value del array?

Éste es el código HTML:

```
<table id="listaderesultados" width="50%" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#006699" class="decotablas"> 
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center" bgcolor="#f7f7f7" class="titulos_tablas"> 
      <td>
        <strong>RESULTADOS</strong>
      </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr align="center" class="textos_reporte"> 
      <td id="question">
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Podríamos ver el HTML donde se tendría que mostrar la imagen?

Comment: Ponlo en la pregunta mejor para que quede mucho más claro a futuros lectores. Tienes un botón de editar justo debajo de la msima.

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta en un momento para que se me entienda mejor.

Comment: @JuanOrtiz Me imagino que esto es una continuación de la [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/134331/250) en la que hablamos. Deberías indicar que estás usando d3.js y no jQuery (porque los usuarios se pueden confundir). Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para mejorar tus preguntas. Sería ideal si en lugar de poner el JS, HTML y JSON por separado, los pusieras todos juntos en un snippet donde se pudiera ver el problema (un [mcve]).

Comment: @alvaroMontoro. ya estoy leyendo esta info, no me habia percatado de esto.

Answer (score 1):

Como te ponía en un [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134331/insertar-datos-en-tabla-html/134346#comment251017_134346) en tu otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/134331/250), lo que quieres se puede hacer agregando un `img` y asignándole la fuente (algo similar al `div` que se iba a insertar entonces).

Si usas `text` entonces lo que vas a hacer es añadir la fuente de la imagen como texto pero no como imagen. Debes agregar la imagen primero (con `append`) y cambiar su atributo `src` después (con `attr`). Algo como esto:

```
.append("img")            // para agregar la imagen
.attr("src", data[0].png) // para asignar el src al valor de data[0].png
```

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
var data = [{
  "label": "DELFIN",
  "value": 0,
  "name": "1",
  "question": "DELFIN",
  "png": "https://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals", //"png/delfin.png",
  "ogg": "ogg/delfin.ogg"
}];

d3.select("#ganadores")
  .append("div")
  .text(data[0].question)
  .append("img")
  .attr('src', data[0].png);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<table id="listadeganadores" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center">RESULTADOS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--   en estos td van los resultados    -->
    <td id="ganadores"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: no me esta funcionando @AlvaroMontoro. 
la cosa es que con lo del texto si pude ubicar el contenido del texto , mas no la imagen como tal .
yo estoy usando el return para ubicar las imagenes.

habria una forma de cambiar esta funcion para que me retorne las imagenes en vez del texto ? 

attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .text( function(d, i) {
                return data[i].value; 
            });

Comment: @JuanOrtiz edita la pregunta para añadir esa información, así como un [mcve] del problema. Es la primera vez que mencionas lo del `text-anchor` y no sé a qué código te refieres o dónde va ese código.